# Dielectric withstand test of DC powered product

Tags: dielectric, hipot

I am trying to figure if our test set-up for dielectric withstand test is correct. There are two versions of the DUT (device under test), an AC powered (typical 85-264 Vrms) and DC powered type (12-24v).

According to what I read, one of the test set-ups is to short the line and neutral line input terminals of the product, and then applying the test voltage between shorted input terminals and any exposed dead metal of enclosure.

In particular, the following is quoted from the manual of HT-PR series:

> The dielectric withstand test is conducted by shorting the line and neutral conductors of the power supply cord and applying high voltage between them and the exposed dead metal of the chassis of the equipment being tested.

Now my problem is that I can't seem to decide if the set-up remains the same if the product to be tested is DC powered. Now, the input terminals is no longer line/neutral but instead +Vdc/gnd.

1. Will the test remain similar such that withstand voltage will be placed between the shorted input terminals (+Vdc/gnd) and any exposed dead metal on enclosure?
2. What if the enclosure of product is fully plastic with no dead/unconnected metal part? Does this mean that this test (shorted supply vs dead metal part) is not applicable to such products, or is the testing applicable regardless if it's fully plastic?

Answer (score 0):

It really depend on what your standard ask… as for the AC/DC the test is the same, you could consider ground as neutral and positive as line. Often DC test are done at lower voltage too.

For the fully plastic enclosed equipment it varies slightly with the test standard but usually there is a special plate electrode to attach the plate (it simulates whatever thing outside the equipment the fault could discharge to).